# ERROR: XXX.cs can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

We've upgraded our SonarQube instance to 6.7 version and since then we see a project failing with below error during SonarQube analysis from VSTS build.

> ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution ERROR: File
>   src/Platform/DeviceProvisioning/Business.Contracts/Models/DeviceDetailsForReplication.cs
>   can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns
>   produce disjoint sets for main and test files ERROR: ERROR: Re-run
>   SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>   The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully

However the same project gets analyzed without any issue in our SonarQube 6.1 instance. To check if the issue is with test file inclusion settings, i tried creating a new SonarQube project with no explicit setting for inclusion\exclusion but i still get the same error on a new project.

Can someone let me know how we can fix the issue.

Comment: Have you tried to `rebuild` and clean out the `bin` and `obj` folders?

Comment: Just guessing, but are there maybe two files `DeviceDetailsForReplication.cs` in your project?

Comment: No! There's only one such file in the source code. Can you let me know what options i can try to debug myself or provide you more information about the error